# overcoming multiple extensions limitations

Tags: typescript

i have an object interface:

```
interface Obj {
    a:string;
    b:string;
}
```

When receiving data from a service i have an interface that would normally have to extend every Obj that i receive;

```
interface ServiceResponse {
    c:string;
    d:string;
}
```

How can i have an interface extending both interfaces, so that i may downcast that object to an Obj? Is there also a better design structure to handle such a case?

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Why doesn't `interface B extends Obj, ServiceResponse {}` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like simply doing

```
interface Both extends Obj, ServiceResponse {

}
```

works for that case. Did I miss something ?

So that would mean the final code resembles to this :

```
interface Obj {
    a:string;
    b:string;
}


interface ServiceResponse {
    c:string;
    d:string;
}

interface Both extends Obj, ServiceResponse {

}

class SomeData implements Both {
    a:string;
    b:string;
    c:string;
    d:string;
}

var test: Obj = new SomeData(); // Works fine
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Obj%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09b%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ServiceResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%09c%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09d%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Both%20extends%20Obj%2C%20ServiceResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SomeData%20implements%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09b%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09c%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09d%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%3A%20Obj%20%3D%20new%20SomeData()%3B%0D%0A)'s the TypeScript Playground of this, and then downcasting the result.

Comment: was tired and made a judgement error in which i thought you could only extend 1 type at every given time (which would be ridiculous).